Why is my segment tree implementation failing for edge and performance test cases when calculating the area of rectangles?
Problem Description:
We are given a list of (axis-aligned) rectangles. Each rectangle[i] = [x1, y1, x2, y2], where (x1, y1) are the coordinates of the bottom-left corner, and (x2, y2) are the coordinates of the top-right corner of the i-th rectangle. We need to find the total area covered by all rectangles in the plane. Since the answer may be very large, return it modulo 10^9 + 7.
Note: y1 will always be 0.

Input Format:

The first line contains an integer N, the number of rectangles.

The next N lines each contain four integers: x1, y1, x2, y2.


Output Format:
Output the total area covered modulo 10^9 + 7.

Constraints:

1 <= N <= 40000

rectanges[i].length = 4

0 <= rectangles[i][j] <= 10^9

The total area covered by all rectangles will never exceed 2^63 - 1 and thus will fit in a 64-bit signed integer



Sample Input 1:
3
0 0 2 2
1 0 2 3
1 0 3 1
Sample Output 1:
6
Explanation 1:
The area of 6 can be seen from this diagram which has the 3 rectangles from the input.
Output image for sample input test case

What I Have Tried:
I have implemented a solution using the segment tree with lazy propagation. Below is my code, which includes logs for debugging purposes.
Code:
import java.util.*;

public class RectangleArea {

    private static final int MOD = 1_000_000_007;

    public long findArea(int n, int[][] rectangles) {
        // Step 1: Coordinate compression for x-coordinates
        TreeSet<Integer> xCoords = new TreeSet<>();
        for (int[] rect : rectangles) {
            xCoords.add(rect[0]);
            xCoords.add(rect[2]);
        }

        // Create mapping for x-coordinates
        List<Integer> xList = new ArrayList<>(xCoords);
        Map<Integer, Integer> xMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < xList.size(); i++) {
            xMap.put(xList.get(i), i);
        }

        // Debugging: Log compressed coordinates mapping
        System.out.println("Compressed X Coordinates Mapping: " + xMap);

        // Step 2: Build events for rectangles
        int[][] events = new int[2 * n][4];
        int index = 0;
        for (int[] rect : rectangles) {
            int x1 = xMap.get(rect[0]), x2 = xMap.get(rect[2]);
            events[index++] = new int[]{rect[1], x1, x2, 1};  // Start event
            events[index++] = new int[]{rect[3], x1, x2, -1}; // End event
        }

        // Sort events by y-coordinate
        Arrays.sort(events, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[0]));

        // Debugging: Log sorted events
        System.out.println("Sorted Events:");
        for (int[] event : events) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(event));
        }

        // Step 3: Segment tree initialization
        int m = xList.size();
        SegmentTree segTree = new SegmentTree(m);

        // Step 4: Process events and calculate total area
        long totalArea = 0;
        int prevY = events[0][0];

        for (int[] event : events) {
            int y = event[0], x1 = event[1], x2 = event[2], type = event[3];

            // Calculate the area covered between prevY and current y
            long width = segTree.query(0, m - 1);
            totalArea = (totalArea + width * (y - prevY)) % MOD;

            // Debugging: Log current status
            System.out.println("Current Y: " + y + ", Prev Y: " + prevY + ", Width: " + width);
            System.out.println("Intermediate Total Area: " + totalArea);

            // Update the segment tree for this event
            segTree.update(x1, x2 - 1, type);

            // Debugging: Log segment tree state after update
            System.out.println("Segment Tree after update for event: " + Arrays.toString(event) + ": " + Arrays.toString(segTree.tree));

            prevY = y;
        }

        return totalArea;
    }

    static class SegmentTree {
        private int[] tree, lazy;
        private int size;

        public SegmentTree(int size) {
            this.size = size;
            this.tree = new int[4 * size];
            this.lazy = new int[4 * size];
        }

        public void update(int l, int r, int val) {
            update(0, 0, size - 1, l, r, val);
        }

        private void update(int node, int start, int end, int l, int r, int val) {
            if (lazy[node] != 0) {
                tree[node] = (lazy[node] > 0) ? (end - start + 1) : 0;
                if (start != end) {
                    lazy[2 * node + 1] += lazy[node];
                    lazy[2 * node + 2] += lazy[node];
                }
                lazy[node] = 0;
            }

            if (start > end || start > r || end < l) return;

            if (start >= l && end <= r) {
                lazy[node] += val;
                tree[node] = (lazy[node] > 0) ? (end - start + 1) : 0;
                if (start != end) {
                    lazy[2 * node + 1] += lazy[node];
                    lazy[2 * node + 2] += lazy[node];
                }
                return;
            }

            int mid = (start + end) / 2;
            update(2 * node + 1, start, mid, l, r, val);
            update(2 * node + 2, mid + 1, end, l, r, val);
            tree[node] = tree[2 * node + 1] + tree[2 * node + 2];
        }

        public long query(int l, int r) {
            return query(0, 0, size - 1, l, r);
        }

        private long query(int node, int start, int end, int l, int r) {
            if (lazy[node] != 0) {
                tree[node] = (lazy[node] > 0) ? (end - start + 1) : 0;
                if (start != end) {
                    lazy[2 * node + 1] += lazy[node];
                    lazy[2 * node + 2] += lazy[node];
                }
                lazy[node] = 0;
            }

            if (start > end || start > r || end < l) return 0;

            if (start >= l && end <= r) return tree[node];

            int mid = (start + end) / 2;
            long left = query(2 * node + 1, start, mid, l, r);
            long right = query(2 * node + 2, mid + 1, end, l, r);
            return left + right;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] rectangles = new int[n][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            rectangles[i][0] = scanner.nextInt();
            rectangles[i][1] = scanner.nextInt();
            rectangles[i][2] = scanner.nextInt();
            rectangles[i][3] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        scanner.close();

        long result = new RectangleArea().findArea(n, rectangles);
        System.out.println("Final Area: " + result);
    }
}


What’s Going Wrong:

Overlapping intervals are not being merged correctly.

Intermediate areas for edge cases fail due to incorrect segment tree updates.

My lazy propagation logic might be flawed for certain cases.

Performance is suboptimal for larger test cases.



Debugging Steps Taken:

Logged compressed coordinates.

Logged sorted events.

Logged intermediate area calculations and segment tree state.

Verified lazy propagation by manually checking tree states.



Question: What am I doing wrong in my segment tree implementation? Could there be a logical flaw in lazy propagation or event handling? If so, how can I fix it? Alternatively, is there a more efficient approach to solve this problem?
